# Stop relative divs scrolling past a certain point

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I stop relative divs scrolling past a certain point?

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7RncF/6/) to help you understand

Basically, I want to be able to scroll as normal, the only difference being is I don't want to see anything behind the header tag, i.e. as it stands when you scroll, you can see the divs through the header tag, I want it so when it scrolls, the cut off point is the bottom of the header tag so when scrolling you won't see anything past the header line.

Hope that makes sense.

Here's the header css

```
#header {
  height:40px;
  width:100%;
  background:transparent;
  position:fixed;
  border:1px solid black;
  top:0;
}
```

Comment: Hi - I don't know whether I'm alone but I'm not really following what you mean- could you explain a bit further ? Perhaps an example layout ?

Comment: please mention that you have got the correct answer or not

Answer (score 0):

You could give your header a (non-`transparent`) `background-color`, or create a new scroll-area below the header with `overflow: scroll/auto`

Answer (score 0):

You use jquery scrollTop for this

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= 229){
      alert("in if");
      $('#header').css({position:'relative'});
    }else{
      alert("in else");
      $('#header').css({position:'fixed'});
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7RncF/11/)

Comment: I don't think that this helps him by this problem. And just by the way, your code is really unperformant!

Answer (score 0):

just modify the css for `#header` as follows :

```
background: white;
```

This happens because you have made the `background` transparent.

for scrolling you can add following jQuery:

```
var windw = this;

$.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(windw);

    $window.scroll(function(e){
        if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
            $this.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: pos
            });
        } else {
            $this.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 0
            });
        }
    });
};

$('#header').followTo(250);
```

Comment: He said =>Stop relative divs scrolling past a certain point.Where is code Related to scrolling?This Question is related to jQuery,Javascript also.